# PHP PDO Select ID

Tags: php, pdo

I'm learning PDO from [NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and have had success so far searching FETCH_ASSOC based on strings.

Question: Which `PDO::` is needed in order to search by integers? I thought it was `PDO::Fetch_OBJ`. The following is returning false.

```
$busid = $this->sanitize($string);

$database->query('SELECT name, address FROM business_information WHERE id = :id', array(':id' => $busid));  
var_dump($database);
    if($database->count() >= '1') {
                $results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
                   while($row = $results->fetch()) { 
                        $test = "Name: ".$row['name']." Address: ".$row['address'];             

    }else{
        $test = "no results were found";

    }
```

var_dump returns:

> object(database)#1 (7) {["pdo":"database":private]=> object(PDO)#2 (0)
>   { } ["port"]=> int(3306) ["statement"]=> object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) {
>   ["queryString"]=> string(61) "SELECT name, address FROM
>   business_information WHERE id = :id" } }

Comment: I recommend you use (and learn from) a simple PDO library like [DByte](https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte).

Comment: I don't recommend you to use that crappy library (DByte) with dirty code. PDO is simple enough to use without any wrappers (PDO is a wrapper already).

Comment: @Xeoncross:  Some disclosure about your relationship to that project would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Prepared statements is better than sanitizing.
2) PDO::query have another signature, read the manual please.

```
/** @var \PDO $PDO */
$query = $PDO->prepare('SELECT name, address FROM business_information WHERE id = :id');
if (!$query) return false;
if (!$query->execute(array(':id' => $busid))) return false;
$results = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (empty($results)) return false;
foreach ($results as $row)
{
    $test = "Name: ".$row['name']." Address: ".$row['address'];
    echo $test, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks OZ! I'll definitively look into prepare statements vs query statements.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to `prepare` a statement before firing it to the database. Why? The answer is somewhere near [PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). When you do use `prepare`, you will find yourself holding a `PDOStatement` as a return value.

Okey. Lets bind values to a placeholder with: [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Take a look at the signature:

```
`bool PDOStatement::bindValue(mixed $parameter,
                              mixed $value
                              [,int $data_type=PDO::PARAM_STR])`
```

`data_type`: Explicit data type for the parameter using the PDO::PARAM_* constants.
You can set `data_type` manually, but is not necessary in 99% of time. (As I've found it out.)